# Reload ServerSideProps after api call (reactjs + nextjs + prisma)

Tags: mysql, reactjs, next.js, prisma

I have a project with objects in mysql containing active boolean.
I've made a button that onclick changes the state of `active` column for object.id with an api call. It works well, but after i click the button mysql state changes but the site stays with old getServerSideProps().

**How can i fast refresh the objects without reloading the page?**

Answer (score 0):

use useState(obj.active) to initial obj.active from getServerSideProps, and after you click, call setState to update the state.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).